# Encapsulando instância estrutura

Tags: c, orientação-a-objetos

Dado o seguinte código, implementar uma pequena biblioteca que torna-o possível.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "object.h"

int main() {
    obj_instance *oi1;
    obj_instance *oi2;
    
    object_init();
    
    oi1 = Object.New();
    oi2 = Object.New();

    Object.Set(oi1, 5);
    Object.Set(oi2, 3);
    
    printf("valor de oi1: %d\n", Object.Get(oi1));
    printf("valor de oi2: %d\n", Object.Get(oi2));

    printf("oi1 y oi2 ");
    if(!Object.Equals(oi1, oi2))
        printf("NO ");
    printf("son iguales.\n");

    Object.Set(oi2, 5);
    
    printf("valor de oi1: %d\n", Object.Get(oi1));
    printf("valor de oi2: %d\n", Object.Get(oi2));
    
    printf("oi1 y oi2 ");
    if(!Object.Equals(oi1, oi2))
        printf("NO ");
    printf("son iguales.\n");
   
    Object.Free(oi1);
    puts("oi1 liberado.");
    
    Object.Free(oi2);
    puts("oi2 liberado.");
}
```

Você não pode alocar memória usando `obj_instance` como um argumento para `malloc`. Ou seja, este código deve falhar:

```
obj_instance *un_objeto = malloc(sizeof(obj_instance));
```

`Object` é uma instância de `obj_instance`? Como eu posso encapsular `obj_instance`?

Comment: Esta biblioteca que você tem que criar tem o conceito de classes? Me parece que no final, esses objetos estão apenas sendo formas incomuns de se encapsular `int`s.

Comment: acho que sim, estou lendo um livro sobre programação orientada a objetos em C

Comment: Você consegue dar um exemplo de código onde o objeto é usado para algo mais complicadinho do que apenas um `int` encapsulado? Ou isso é algo que será abordado apenas em capítulos posteriores do livro e a ideia aqui é apenas abrir caminho para conceitos mais avançados que serão introduzidos posteriormente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se é isso o que você precisa exatamente, mas para atingir o propósito que você pede, eu faria o seguinte:

Arquivo `"object.h"`:

```
typedef struct obj_instance obj_instance;

typedef struct Object_vtable {
    void (*Set)(obj_instance *, int);
    int (*Get)(obj_instance *);
    int (*Equals)(obj_instance *, obj_instance *);
    obj_instance *(*New)();
    void (*Free)();
} Object_vtable;

extern Object_vtable Object;

void object_init();
```

Arquivo `"object.c"`:

```
import "object.h"

typedef struct obj_instance {
    int value;
} obj_instance;

Object_vtable Object;

void Set(obj_instance *instance, int value) {
    instance->value = value;
}

int Get(obj_instance *instance) {
    return instance->value;
}

int Equals(obj_instance *a, obj_instance *b) {
    return a->value == b->value;
}

obj_instance *New() {
    obj_instance *instance = (obj_instance *) malloc(sizeof(obj_instance));
    instance->value = 0;
    return instance;
}

void Free(obj_instance *instance) {
    free(instance);
}

void object_init() {
    Object.New = New;
    Object.Free = Free;
    Object.Equals = Equals;
    Object.Get = Get;
    Object.Set = Set;
}
```

A ideia aqui é usar uma [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), basicamente uma estrutura que contém vários ponteiros para funções. Isso é o análogo a uma classe e cada um desses ponteiros de função o análogo a um método.

A estrutura `Object` é do tipo `Object_vtable`, e há apenas uma dessas declaradas de forma estática. Ela serve como a definição de uma classe.

O `malloc` existe dentro do `object.c`. Mas a tentativa de fazê-lo no `main.c` vai dar errado porque o cabeçalho `object.h` contém apenas `typedef struct obj_instance obj_instance`. Tentar acessar o atributo `value` diretamente no `main.c` também dará erro de compilação (ele é privado). Com isso, ao analisar o `main.c`, o compilador saberá que existe uma estrutura chamada `obj_instance`, mas não saberá o conteúdo dela, e portanto também não saberá o seu tamanho, logo o `sizeof` do `malloc` vai falhar. Essas informações somente estarão disponível para o compilador dentro do `object.c` e só aparecerão ao programa como um todo na etapa de linkedição.

Isso tudo ainda é algo bastante primitivo em transformar C em uma linguagem orientada-a-objetos. Ainda não há o conceito de subclasses, nem de polimorfismo e nem de interfaces, embora já se tenha algo que vai vir a ser um construtor, um destrutor e alguns métodos. Também dá para se ter uma ideia como implementar o conceito de público e privado, vez que nesse código resultante, o atributo `value` é privado e os métodos são públicos. Métodos do tipo `is_instance` e `get_class` também serão úteis mais para frente, bem como fazer com que as estruturas que representem as classes sejam também, elas mesmas objetos. Isso tudo, você implementará mais tarde.

Comment: tipo de dados obj_instance eles só podem ser acessados ​​através das funções de biblioteca Object.Función; I apologize'm no trabalho e eu não consigo compilar muito obrigado pela sua resposta a sério

Comment: @cheroky Que erro de compilação você teve?

Comment: Não consigo compilar porque eu estou no trabalho Eu só queria saber se os objetos obj_instance só podem ser acessados ​​através de funções Object.set Object.get etc. apenas funções de membro

Comment: @cheroky Sim, apenas o que está no `object.h` é visível dentro do `main.h`. As demais partes que estão no `object.c` ficam encapsuladas e são privadas.

Comment: Muito obrigado quando eu chegar em casa eu vou começar a estudar o seu código